# Inconveniente con envio de datos de una pagina a otra mediante jsp

Tags: java, jsp, aplicación-web

Cordial saludo equipo espero se encuentren bien, necesito pedirles un favor con lo siguiente requerimiento:

envío mediante un enlace de una pagina de origen con nombre ListadoClientes a otra pagina con nombre ListadoProyecto, lo siguiente:

este es el codigo que tengo de la pagina ListadoClientes:

```
<th> <a href="ListadoProyecto.jsp?txtNit=<%=nit%>&ListadoProyecto.jsp?txtNombrecli=<%=nombrecli%>"><%=rs.getString(1)%></th>
```

Y este es el codigo que tengo de la pagina ListadoProyecto:

```
<%
 String txtNit,txtNombrecli;
          
  txtNit=request.getParameter("txtNit");
  txtNombrecli=request.getParameter("txtNombrecli");
%> 
<h1><%=txtNit %></h1> 
<h1><%=txtNombrecli %></h1>
```

Al realizar lo anterior en la pagina ListadoProyecto, solo me imprime el Nit del cliente
(

## <%=txtNit %>

), más no el nombre del cliente (

## <%=txtNombrecli %>

)
se me hace exreaño que no me lo imprima debido a que si aparece en la url cuando envio el valor desde
el formulario ListadoClientes (http://localhost:8080/NorgasCodFac/Admin/.../ListadoProyecto.jsp?txtNit=771031&ListadoProyecto.jsp?txtNombrecli=ELC)

Muchas gracias por su colaboración!.

Answer (score 0):

Esta mal la url, con que le mandes una vez el destino debe funcionar, prueba así
`<a href="ListadoProyecto.jsp?txtNit=<%=nit%>&txtNombrecli=<%=nombrecli%>"><%=rs.getString(1)%>`